# understanding the return keyword

Tags: javascript, return

I have this:

```
validateForm = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < formInputs.length; i++) {
        const inputName = formInputs[i];

        if (!this.state.form[inputName].length) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

which im refactoring in to this:

```
validateForm2 = () => {
    Object.keys(this.state.form).map(input => {
        if(!this.state.form[input].length) {
            return false
        }
        return true;
    })
}
```

the first one works, when i fill in my form and the function returns true, if one is empty it returns false.

however i cant seem to quite understand the `return` keyword to get the same result.
Object.keys says it returns an array but even if I say `return Object.keys...` or `else {return true}` I don't seem to get the same result. what am I misunderstanding about return?

Comment: The latter doesn't return anything from the called function (`validateForm2`), only from the `map`'s callback function.

Comment: @Teemu yes true, but if I put a return in front of Object.keys it still is broken?

Comment: Yep, because `map` is not for the task. Please see some answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify your function to do what you want it to do.

```
validateForm2 = () => {
    return Object.keys(this.state.form).every(input => {
      return this.state.form[input].length;
    })
  }
```

You are checking that every property has a length (true). If one of them doesn't, your function returns false.

Comment: this is what's confusing me. I do this. I then run this:
`
  handleSubmit = () => {
    if (this.validateForm2()) {
      console.log('Success!');
    } else {
      console.log('Failure!');
    }
  }
`
and it logs success when I leave it blank?!?

Comment: Well, show us what you have inside this.state.form. Are you sure there are empty properties? Every property is a string?

Comment: weird, works now. cheers! can you just quickly explain why this works but `return Object.keys..` with an if statement afterwards wouldnt work?

Comment: what wasn't working in your example was: 1) the .map method, it returns a new array with whatever you return. 2) you weren't returning anything from that function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: so basically, it's the difference between map and every

Comment: and also that you need to return something truthty / falsy from your function.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you have only one (arrow) function which returns either `false` or `undefined`.

In the second example you have outer (arrow) function that never returns anything - `undefined` to the calling code, and the second function that you pass as a parameter to `Array.map` method. `return` statements inside the parameter function are not returning anything from the outer function.

```
validateForm2 = () => {
  var emptyItems = Object.keys(this.state.form).filter(input => {
      return !this.state.form[input].length;
  });
  return emptyItems.length == 0;
}
```

Comment: ok but if I `return Object.keys...` why does this not fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), which uses the return value for a short circuit and for returning the check of all truthy items.

```
validateForm2 = () =>
    Object.keys(this.state.form).every(input => this.state.form[input].length);
```

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) utilizes the return value as new item for each item of the array for a new array, which is dicarded in the given example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can avoid using `.map` in favor of `.every()` which iterates over every single element and checks whether it has a length greater than zero.

```js
const validateForm = (form) => Object.values(form).every((field) => field.length);
let semiEmptyForm = {
firstField : "",
secondfield : "notEmpty"
};
let nonEmptyForm = {
firstField : "notEmpty",
secondfield : "notEmpty"
};
console.log(validateForm(semiEmptyForm))
console.log(validateForm(nonEmptyForm))
```